# Change iOS system prompt language when app language is different from system language

Tags: ios, swift, localization

In the application I'm developing, the user has the possibility to change the language. Therefore, the app language can be different than the iOS language.

The problem I'm facing is when a system prompt is shown within the application (i.e. Touch ID prompt), it uses the system language and not the app language. Is there any way of "forcing" the system prompts language?

Comment: From what I know, it is not possible. You can only change the language of the message of the prompt (the message to explain why you use this feature), but not the title.

Comment: Thanks @qtngo. This is my guess too. I just want to make sure I wasn't missing a workaround

Answer (score 0):

As @qtngo mentioned, it is not possible.